# Difference between Wolfram Cloud basic and upgraded version

Tags: wolfram-cloud, mathematica-online

I am teaching a course this semester which requires the usage of Mathematica for doing simple analytical calculations. Now, our school doesn't offer Mathematica license for free. I checked out Mathematica Online (wolframcloud.com). And it seems like for free, I can do most calculations online. What are the limitations of Mathematica Online? What type of Calculations cannot be done there?

Comment: One of the big differences is unpaid has a sixty day after creation file expiration.